# A problem when adding a new text to the to-do-list

Tags: javascript, jquery

why when i add a new text it adds to all of the element?

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  let newTask = $('#input-text');
  if (newTask.val() === '') {
    alert('You need to write something');
  } else {
    let editButton = ('<button class = edit > Edit' + '</button>');
    let finishedButton = ('<button class = finished > Finished' + '</button>');
    let deleteButton = ('<button class = delete > Delete' + '</button>');
    let input = ('<input class= input>');

    $('#toDoList').append('<li>' + input + editButton + finishedButton + deleteButton + '</li>');
    $('.input').attr('value', newTask.val());
    newTask.val('');
  }
  
  $('.edit').on('click', function() {
    $('.input').prop('disabled', false);
  });
  
  $('.finished').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent();
    $('#completed').append($(this).parent());
  });

  $('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 300px auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 100px #888888;
  min-height: 450px;
  max-height: auto;
}

.completed {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.to-do {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input {
  margin-top:
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #004690;
}

.color {
  color: green;
}

.color1 {
  color: red;
}

#input-text {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>todo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text">To Do App</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="input-text" type="text" name="" value="">
      <button id="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="to-do">
      <h3 class="text color1">TO-do-list</h3>
      <hr>

      <ul id="toDoList">


      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="completed">
      <h3 class="text color">Completed</h3>
      <hr>
      <ul id="completed">


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This line causes that: `$('.input').attr('value', newTask.val());`. It puts `newTask.val()` in all elements with a class of `input`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code that are outside of the scope of your question which I've decided to ignore.

The issue is with this line, which is using a [class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select all your inputs and update their value.

```
$('.input').attr('value', newTask.val());
```

The simplest solution is to create your input markup with the value included using string interpolation, like this:

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  let newTask = $('#input-text');
  if (newTask.val() === '') {
    alert('You need to write something');
  } else {
    let editButton = ('<button class = edit > Edit' + '</button>');
    let finishedButton = ('<button class = finished > Finished' + '</button>');
    let deleteButton = ('<button class = delete > Delete' + '</button>');

    // Use string interpolation to create input markup with value already defined
    let input = `<input class="input" value="${newTask.val()}">`;

    // Append as usual
    $('#toDoList').append('<li>' + input + editButton + finishedButton + deleteButton + '</li>');

    // Below line is no longer needed so is commented out
    //$('.input').attr('value', newTask.val());

    // Your code continues unmodified
    newTask.val('');
  }
  
  $('.edit').on('click', function() {
    $('.input').prop('disabled', false);
  });
  
  $('.finished').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent();
    $('#completed').append($(this).parent());
  });

  $('.delete').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500, function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: ;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 300px auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 100px #888888;
  min-height: 450px;
  max-height: auto;
}

.completed {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.to-do {
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

#btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.input {
  margin-top:
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  color: #004690;
}

.color {
  color: green;
}

.color1 {
  color: red;
}

#input-text {
  margin-left: 100px;
}

hr {
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>todo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text">To Do App</h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="input-text" type="text" name="" value="">
      <button id="btn">Add</button>
    </div>
    <div class="to-do">
      <h3 class="text color1">TO-do-list</h3>
      <hr>

      <ul id="toDoList">


      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="completed">
      <h3 class="text color">Completed</h3>
      <hr>
      <ul id="completed">


      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/todo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank u so match

Comment: Thanks, @RobMoll! I added that in to make my sample more complete after testing and neglected to comment it out. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @MohamadAlhanbali, thank me by voting up and marking as the answer ;-)

Comment: I'm adding one as well since your answer is awesome. Template literals for the win!